# Switch between actual and forecasted values of exogenous variables in forecast::tsCV function

Tags: r, forecasting, cross-validation

I am using `forecast::tsCV` function in R to perform a rolling origin forecast of 1 day to 1 year ahead horizons using  daily frequency data.
Suppose my outcome variable is y, and I have x1, x2 and x3 as exogenous variables.

If I want to use the actual values of x1, x2 and x3 for training and testing sample to perform  a seven day ahead out of sample forecast, then it would be as:

```r
xreg <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)

fit <- function(x, h, xreg, newxreg) {
  forecast(Arima(x, order=c(1,0,1), xreg=xreg), xreg=newxreg)
}

e <- forecast::tsCV(y, fit, h=7, window=1000, xreg=xreg)
```

However, the problem is that I want to use the actual values of x1 and x2 for the training sample and their forecasted values for the rest of the period.

So I have forecasted values of x1 and x2, lets call them f_x1 and f_x2.
If the first forecast point 1007, x1, x2 and x3 have to be used for 1 to 1000, then switch to f_x1 and f_x2 from 1001 to 1007, and this have to roll over as the windows roll.

I have tried this one:

```r
xreg1=contains x1, x2 and x3
xreg2= contains f_x1, f_x2, x3
then:
e <tsCV(price, fit, h=7,
window =1000,
if (length(xreg) < 1001) {
xreg=xreg1
} else if (length(xreg) > 1000) {
xreg=xreg2
})
```

But the output shows that it doesn't convert using data from xtreg 1 to xtreg2.

Can someone help me how can I develop the `forecast::tsCV` function to perform this?

---

Thanks for the answer,
Its from PackageName::forecast

Comment: Which R package is `tsCV`? Please edit, for example by giving the function in the form `PackageName::tsCV`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Its from PackageName::forecast

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to rewrite the tsCV function to implement this. The way it is written assumes that there is only one xreg row for each time period, but you are wanting to have a different xreg depending on whether the row is being used for training data or test data.

The function itself is not very long, and written only in R, so should not be difficult to adapt. Your new function will need to have two xreg arguments, one with actual values and one with forecasted values. Then you just need to switch to using the forecasted version when creating `xreg_future` in the function. The `xreg_subset` variable should use the actual values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, if I understan correctly, newxreg in forecast function is to be applied as test data and there is no need to use loop, am I correct? but I could not find any example on how to implement it.

Comment: You will still need the loop. Inside the loop you will see there are two variables used: `xreg_subset` and `xreg_future`. The `xreg_future` variable needs to be modified as I have explained.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.